# Why my Service getting stop whenever i close my app in Android?

Tags: android, service

I am writing a Sample Service in Android , to check whether the service is getting stop after closing the app. But in onStartCommand , i have given START_NOT_STICKY as the return type to avoid the auto-restart of my Service.

**MyCode:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.sampleintentservice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class);

     MainActivity.this.startService(i);    

} }
```

**TestService.java**

```
package com.example.sampleintentservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class TestService extends Service
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {        
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {        
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 

        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {        
        return null;
    }}
```

this is my above code , i don't understand when i close my app , the service is getting stop. Please help me out , Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: "Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities."

Comment: ^^ From: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: can you please suggest me  , how can i use thread in my Service

Comment: Follow the link, read and decide what suits you best.

Comment: what do you mean by " when i close my app "? does it mean when you finish() the Activity that started your service?

Comment: simple man , " when i close my app " means , the moment when i  swipe up the app icon from slide menu in the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `startForeground()`

http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/samples/android-7/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ForegroundService.java.shtml

btw, How do you know that the service is stopped? according to what you have described, this should not happen